# Encryption/decryption functions working differently within Outlook add-in versus unit tests

Tags: javascript, encryption, outlook, outlook-web-addins, smime

I am working on an Outlook add-in that S/MIME encrypts/decrypts an email that you are currently composing. I have two functions shown at the end that perform S/MIME encryption/decryption respectively utilizing PKI.js. When running unit tests testing their functionality/correctness, they both work just fine, however when calling the very same functions from within an Outlook add-in (called when buttons are pressed) using the same certificate/key as the unit tests, I encounter the following error when attempting to decrypt some previously encrypted text:

```
Error: Decryption failed
    at RsaOaepProvider.onDecrypt (webcrypto.es.js:1136)
    at RsaOaepProvider.decrypt (webcrypto-core.es.js:173)
    at SubtleCrypto.decrypt (webcrypto-core.es.js:826)
    at CryptoEngine.decrypt (CryptoEngine.js:809)
    at SubKeyTransRecipientInfo (EnvelopedData.js:1454)
```

The following is a unit test that passes just fine (Jest framework configured to run as though it were running in a browser):

```
const plaintext = "This is some plaintext.";

test("encrypt and decrypt some plaintext", async () => {
  const encryptedText = await smimeEncrypt(plaintext, cert);
  const decryptedText = await smimeDecrypt(encryptedText, key, cert);
  expect(decryptedText).toBe(plaintext);
});
```

Versus the code called (that errors) whenever a button is pressed within the Outlook add-in:

```
let encryptedText = await smimeEncrypt(emailBody, cert);

await smimeDecrypt(encryptedText, key, cert).then((decryptedText) => {
    console.log(decryptedText);
}).catch((err) => {
    // Problem decrypting
    console.error("Couldn't decrypt email. (Not an S/MIME message?)", err);
    return;
});
```

I've verified that the emailBody being passed into smimeEncrypt() within the Outlook add-in is the actual email body string that it should be and not blank or anything else. Again, the exact same certificate and key are used for the unit tests that are used within the Outlook add-in itself, so an invalid cert/key pair should not be the issue.

`emailFunctions.ts`

```
import { Crypto } from "@peculiar/webcrypto";
import * as asn1js from "asn1js";
import { Convert } from "pvtsutils";
import * as pkijs from "pkijs";

import MimeNode from "emailjs-mime-builder";
import smimeParse from "emailjs-mime-parser";

// Set crypto engine
const crypto = new Crypto();
const engineName = "@peculiar/webcrypto";
pkijs.setEngine(
  engineName,
  crypto,
  new pkijs.CryptoEngine({ name: engineName, crypto: crypto, subtle: crypto.subtle })
);

async function smimeEncrypt(
  text: string,
  certificatePem: string,
  oaepHashAlgo: string = "SHA-256",
  encryptionAlgo: string = "AES-CBC",
  length: Number = 128
): Promise<string> {
  // Decode input certificate
  const asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(PemConverter.decode(certificatePem)[0]);
  const certSimpl = new pkijs.Certificate({ schema: asn1.result });

  const cmsEnveloped = new pkijs.EnvelopedData();

  cmsEnveloped.addRecipientByCertificate(certSimpl, { oaepHashAlgorithm: oaepHashAlgo });

  await cmsEnveloped.encrypt({ name: encryptionAlgo, length: length }, Convert.FromUtf8String(text));

  const cmsContentSimpl = new pkijs.ContentInfo();
  cmsContentSimpl.contentType = "1.2.840.113549.1.7.3";
  cmsContentSimpl.content = cmsEnveloped.toSchema();

  const schema = cmsContentSimpl.toSchema();
  const ber = schema.toBER(false);

  // Insert enveloped data into new Mime message
  const mimeBuilder = new MimeNode("application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m; smime-type=enveloped-data; charset=binary")
    .setHeader("content-description", "Enveloped Data")
    .setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=smime.p7m")
    .setHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "base64")
    .setContent(new Uint8Array(ber));
  mimeBuilder.setHeader("from", "sender@example.com");
  mimeBuilder.setHeader("to", "recipient@example.com");
  mimeBuilder.setHeader("subject", "Example S/MIME encrypted message");

  return mimeBuilder.build();
}

async function smimeDecrypt(text: string, privateKeyPem: string, certificatePem: string): Promise<string> {
  // Decode input certificate
  let asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(PemConverter.decode(certificatePem)[0]);
  const certSimpl = new pkijs.Certificate({ schema: asn1.result });

  // Decode input private key
  const privateKeyBuffer = PemConverter.decode(privateKeyPem)[0];

  // Parse S/MIME message to get CMS enveloped content
  try {
    const parser = smimeParse(text);

    // Make all CMS data
    asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(parser.content.buffer);
    if (asn1.offset === -1) {
      alert('Unable to parse your data. Please check you have "Content-Type: charset=binary" in your S/MIME message');
      return;
    }

    const cmsContentSimpl = new pkijs.ContentInfo({ schema: asn1.result });
    const cmsEnvelopedSimpl = new pkijs.EnvelopedData({ schema: cmsContentSimpl.content });

    const message = await cmsEnvelopedSimpl.decrypt(0, {
      recipientCertificate: certSimpl,
      recipientPrivateKey: privateKeyBuffer,
    });

    return Convert.ToUtf8String(message);
  } catch (err) {
    // Not an S/MIME message
    throw err;
  }
}
```

The full project repo can be found at https://github.com/gmu-msl/pkijs_outlook_addin_example, with some additional details and directions on how to install and test the behavior locally. Any insight as to what is causing this discrepancy and/or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure we can assist with your specific add-in error, as it appears to be quite specific to your own add-in. However, what Platform are you on? (Win32, Mac, OWA) and what Build # of that version? Is it possible you could simplify the repro to a specific call that is failing, and what the difference is between the working and non-working scenarios? Is it possible that you are reaching out to another library/service somewhere, and it is not reachable from inside the add-in sandbox?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I am on OWA (Chrome Version 91.0.4472.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)), with the add-in being hosted locally from a Windows 7 Professional, Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) instance. The specific call that's failing is crypto.decrypt() at EnvelopedData.js:1454. The only difference is that the unit tests are being run entirely locally, while the Outlook add-in is obviously being run in Outlook's sandbox environment (same cert, private key, & string passed). As for non-reachable libraries, I believe only PKI.js could be using one under the covers for crypto.

Comment: The result of the encrypt function and input to decrypt function looks identical. Have you tried decrypting the same text outside of the Add-in environment? Also, is this working for you in Windows or any other Platform?

Comment: Yes, attempting to decrypt the encrypted text generated within the Add-in results in the same error, however attempting the opposite (taking encrypted text generated outside the Add-in and decrypting it within the Add-in) results in proper decryption as expected. This leads me to believe that the encryption from within the Outlook Add-in is behaving differently compared to outside the Add-in environment and is the culprit. Is it possible that there is something the Add-in environment is doing under the covers to modify something to do with the browser's Webcrypto?

Comment: Have you tried this on Windows or any other platform if it is working there?

Comment: Yes, on both Firefox 89.0.2 (64-bit) and the Windows client it's getting stuck indefinitely on "working on your Encrypt current email request", although it still reaches through on Chrome just fine. On Mac's Safari browser, the add-in works similarly to Chrome running on Windows (still generates what looks to be valid S/MIME encrypted text, but can't decrypt). And finally on Mac's Outlook client, it successfully completes the encrypt button action, but always sets the email body to be blank. I believe this to be because the generated S/MIME text is too long (slicing the text to be shorter)

Comment: I believe the Firefox and Windows client issues could be a local configuration problem, so I will be trying to replicate it on another machine and will post an update on whether or not it works. As for the Mac Outlook behavior, is this a known bug? The Outlook API docs state that the input may be no longer than 1,000,000 characters, however from my experimentation it seems to only work when setting up to 440 characters, otherwise it will just set the body to be blank.

Comment: The Firefox (and I suspect the Windows client as well, but can't confirm yet) connection issues ended up being caused by Firefox not trusting the self-signed certificate used to host the add-in locally. I added localhost as an exception to Firefox, which solved the indefinite "working on your Encrypt current email request", and got it to properly resolve and set the email body as expected. However, the problem of not seeming to be able to generate valid S/MIME text was also present within the Firefox environment, similarly to Chrome and Safari.

Comment: We tried Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync API, and it works just fine for us. We tried upto 500 characters. Can you try to reproduce this issue with simple dummy text of more than 440 characters. 
If the issue still repros please share you MAC Outlook build number and whether you are using old UI or New UI.